Plotting a function that is a string in matplotlib // interpreting a str as python code?
I am creating an RPN calculator that tries to plot the function given by a user. For example, if a user inputs "x sin 3 * plot" I would expect it to plot sin(x)*3. The code for this is below. Note: the problem is under if prompt=="plot"
userInputX=""               #userInputX is always replaced before
                            #running again, so it can be set once here
while True:        
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    if not myqueue.isEmpty(): # Display both postfix and infix
        print("Postfix: "+str(myqueue))
        print("Infix: "+StackCalc.postfix2infix(myqueue))
    prompt=input(">")
    if prompt == "exp" or prompt == "^": prompt = "**"  #<- Easiest way to stop errors with eval(),
    if prompt=="quit": break                            #+ consistent formatting while still accepting exp/^

    if prompt=="run":
        if myqueue.find("x") is True:                   # If run, get x value from user, set post2in to the 
            userInputX=input("Enter x value: ")         #result of postfix2infix except replace the x with userinput
        post2in=StackCalc.postfix2infix(myqueue).replace("x",userInputX)
        print("Solution using infix:",eval(post2in))    #then evaluate it
        print("Solution using postfix:",StackCalc.evaluate_postfix(myqueue,userInputX))
        continue #skip to next iteration, as "run" shouldnt be pushed to queue

    if prompt=="plot":
        post2in=StackCalc.postfix2infix(myqueue)
        usrInp=input("Enter values of xmin, xmax, nbp: ")#input format "0.5 10.5 1"
        usrInp=usrInp.split()                       # Make it a list,
        xmin,xmax,nbp=usrInp[0],usrInp[1],usrInp[2] #set values to input
        
        #this is where it gets questionable
        x=np.linspace(float(xmin),float(xmax),int(nbp))
        plt.plot(x,post2in)   # this is specifically where the issue lies
        plt.title("f(x)="+str(post2in))
        plt.show()
        continue # dont push "plot" to queue


    if prompt!="flush":
        if prompt == "exp" or prompt == "^": prompt = "**"
        myqueue.enqueue(prompt)     # same code as optn. 2
    else:
        myqueue.flush()

To be clear, postfix2infix returns the user's function as a string. For the example I used above, it would return "sin(x)*3" as a string, which I need to interpret as a function/python code instead. Is this possible?

No minimal working example, it's really opaque. Then, it looks an XY problem, RPN calculators are usually implemented in a different way.

To provide a working example, would I just provide the output of the calculator? If so, I can add that to the post

eval() can still be used on user-inputted strings that contain x, so the solution is simply changing plt.plot(x,post2in) to plt.plot(x, eval(post2in)).

Using eval might be okay for your specific case (as a homework assignment), but its use is generally frowned upon, especially for code that you might release (if you end up in a programming career).

@jared Yes certainly- I am heavily interested in cybersecurity (computer engineering major), and I know all too well to NEVER trust userinput, although if the code being run through eval() is only being run on that same user's computer from their own input, it is probably generally ok.

For this case, you might want to look into using sympy, specifically the sympify function and then on that you can do lambdify (to turn it into a Python function that you can pass your x into).

In a sympify guide it states that it internally uses eval(), and can only be avoided by setting evaluate=False in the args. ie, sympify(post2in,evaluate=False) which is why I assume you said to use lambdify, although it says that lambdify uses exec() internally, and I don't see a way to avoid that. So, it seems like using that would be a roundabout way to run eval() // exec() regardless? If I'm wrong, please correct me.

I haven't dug into the code enough to say. I thought they had safer implementations, but I might be wrong.
